# Generate all possible splittings

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I am looking the fastest algo for the following task. I have some array

[a,b,c ... ]

and I need to generate some equally random array of arrays that contains all elements of main array, something like this:

```
Input [1 2 3 4 5 ] => [ [1 2 ] [3 4 ] [ 5 ] ]
```

Straitforward solution is to generate all splittings and randomly choose one of them . This solution guarantees that all splittings will be chosen with equal probability. But Its too slow for big numbers. Is there the other possibility to create this splitting?

Comment: do you have to split items at the beginning? if not, you can do it when it is needed. it may save both space and time. assume that you have to split array with 3-element subarrays, when you need some random element inside, you can just generate `x = rand % (n/3)` and get the elements in `x*3`, `x*3+1`, `x*3+2`. this is just a solution for the case that they are not needed all at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each possible splitting point, randomly decide whether or not to split there. For example, in Python:

```
import random

def random_split(input_list):
    result = [[]]

    # Assume input is nonempty, since it's not clear what the result should
    # be if the input is empty.
    result[-1].append(input_list[0])

    for item in input_list[1:]:
        if random.randrange(2):
            # Split here.
            result.append([])
        result[-1].append(item)

    return result
```

Comment: This favors many splits (in the order of `N/2`, where `N` is the list length), i.e. it is not uniform in the space of all splittings.

Comment: @davidhigh: But that's exactly what you'd expect from a uniform distribution. You can easily see that the average number of splits in a splitting is (N-1)/2, since each possible splitting corresponds to a second splitting where you split everywhere the first splitting doesn't and you don't split anywhere the first splitting did.

Comment: Thinking it over again, I think you're right.(and my intuition was wrong).

Comment: Just to correct myself: an easy proof that it's uniform is given by induction (as you mentioned). For two elements, the algo is seen to give a uniform distribution. Start with list length `N` and assume that the algo is uniform. Then for length `N+1` one has two times as many possible splits which are both uniformly distributed. Schematically one has `"1/2 uniform + 1/2 uniform"`, which is uniform by itself.